# Illinois Standard Marital Interrogatories

Tags: illinois, interrogation

Illinois Supreme Court allows for up to 30 questions to be asked in Interrogatories. However it's not clear what constitutes a question.

The Standard form appears to have 27 questions, but there seems to be confusion around if the subpart questions are considered standalone questions or not.

I've been unable to find any information on the production of the Standard form and anything else related to how to interpret if a question is a discrete subpart or not.

It seems odd to me that the Standard form would be typeset with 27 enumerated questions, if that didn't mean that the subparts are not discrete, thus allowed within the enumerated question.